# Buffering large size HTML Page into C++ Buffer

Tags: html, c++, node.js, browser, webserver

In my scenario I have to pass the WEBSERVER response data to a browser(client) which runs in a remote place. I have developed a intermediate in C++ which takes data from WEBSERVER(by hitting IP and Port)and passes it to client browser. Problem is when my C++ intermediate hits on the WEBSERVER (IP and Port, it returns a huge chunk of data(All most whole code 25 MB) which my C++ buffer is not able to handle. Please suggest any way to handle the data so that i can pass it on to the browser client and web page could be displayed.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to familiarize yourself with the site mechanics. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What do you mean with "*my C++ buffer is not able to handle*"? How did you implement your buffer? How is it getting filled?

Comment: Use a bigger buffer? An `std::vector<char>` will continue to grow as long as you `push_back()`.

Comment: I have a Char buffer to store the response from WEBSERVER but unable to read the response because of it huge size. I want to know is there any thing where we can read the response in chunks.  WebServer returns the whole code when i print the buffer .